# PING Kali Linux

Tags: command-line, terminal, ping, kali-linux

Okay. So, I just installed Kali Linux 2018.1 on my computer as the host operating system. And I have a wired internet connection. So, I opened the terminal to use `ping yahoo.com` and I get this:

```
PING yahoo.com (72.30.35.10) 56(84) bytes of data
```

And after that... nothing. The cursor keeps blinking and nothing happens. I waited for 15 minutes but nothing else comes up. I tried typing other commands like `cls exit` but they don't even respond. Then, as I typed `Ctrl + C` to end, I got:

```
^C
--- kali.org ping statistics ---
213 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 217095ms
```

At first I thought maybe I am not connected to the internet but that's not case because I'm using Firefox on my Kali OS to write this question.
So, can anyone please tell me that I am doing wrong here... quick?

Comment: Your question is really hard to read. Please [edit] it to improve readability. Proper capitalization, punctuation and paragraphs will help a lot.

Comment: Can you ping the router/default gateway IP address?

Comment: What does ifconfig give you?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

then, do this to see if any extra rules blocking anything

```
iptables -nL
```

check out other commands such as `traceroute` and `mtr`, `arp` if needed.
Of course you set firewall and things back to what they were.

```
systemctl start firewalld
```

You can also switch back to iptables if you are familiar with firewalld yet.